# Not able to open Nvidia X Server settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04

Laptop: Asus Zenbook UX430UN-GV020T

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001D10sv00001043sd00001C20bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP108M [GeForce MX150]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
$ <reboot>

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

$ sudo apt show nvidia-390
Package: nvidia-390
Version: 390.67-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Source: nvidia-graphics-drivers-390
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Installed-Size: 20.5 kB
Depends: nvidia-driver-390
Download-Size: 8,044 B
APT-Sources: http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Description: Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390
This is a transitional package for nvidia-driver-390, and can be
safely removed after the installation is complete.

$ sudo apt show nvidia-396
N: Unable to locate package nvidia-396
N: Unable to locate package nvidia-396
E: No packages found
```

I'm not sure why is the version 390, when the recommended driver was 396.
But trying to open Nvidia X Server settings does not do anything.
Any help guys?

Comment: What's wrong with version 390?

Comment: Tried that too, this time I just tried the default tools. Both didn't work :(

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? Having the same issues....

Comment: I tried so many methods that at one point I encountered the login loop; and then I decided to reinstall the whole thing. After that, it just worked.